# How to interpret Database files and size?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a database and I'm trying to determine the max size that it can grow to, but I'm confused by what I'm seeing.

The size of the database is reporting as 781GB with 1.8GB available (space remaining that's reserved, as I understand).
There are 2 db files and 1 log file configured - I don't know who added the second db file as I didn't, but this part adds to my confusion.

The "Maxsize" for the first one is 166GB and the second is 730GB. The total of these combined is 896GB.

1. Is this (896GB) the max size that the DB can grow to?
2. If so, how is that data from tables divided up into these two files?
3. Is this good practice to have two files configured? Both D and M drives are on independent disks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this (896GB) the max size that the DB can grow to?

According to your screenshot, unless someone changes the maximum size, yes.

> If so, how is that data from tables divided up into these two files?

Extents are allocated based on [round robin and proportional fill](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/investigating-the-proportional-fill-algorithm/).

> Is this good practice to have two files configured?

This is an "it depends" answer, and the true answer depends on various factors and design goals. There's no one size fits all, but there is a bad thing in one file fits all (as in, don't have a single giant 15.9 TB file).